# Delete rows from sqlite3 DB not in a list of objects

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a list containing some 'product' objects and want to delete all the products row in the DB that are not in that list based on their unique attribute `serialNumber`.

Example, if my list contain:

- product A
- product B
- product C

My DB contain:

- product A
- product B
- product C
- product D

Then I want to remove product D from the DB.

This is my list:

```
List<Product> products;
```

I'm thinking of looping on the list to create a string array `serialNumbers` of `serialNumber`.

```
String[] serialNumbers;

for (int i=0; i<products.size(); i++){
    //Insert serialNumbers in Array
}
```

and then something like:

```
database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PRODUCTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SERIALNUMBER + " NOT IN " + SerialNumbers, null);
```

How could I do the database query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the inQuery like this:

```
StringBuilder inQuery = new StringBuilder();

inQuery.append("(");
boolean first = true;
for (String item : serialNumbers) {
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        inQuery.append("'").append(item).append("'");
    } else {
        inQuery.append(", '").append(item).append("'");
    }
}
inQuery.append(")");
```

then use it:

```
database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PRODUCTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SERIALNUMBER + " NOT IN " + inQuery.toString(), null);
```